# How did I lose $80 in an ETH to DYP swap on Uniswap?

Tags: blockchain, transactions

I swapped $786.37 worth of ETH for DYP and only received $705.86 worth DYP. The gas fee was only $2.77 so how did I lose $77.74 of value in the transaction?[image]

Comment: Can you share the tx hash? You might have gotten frontrun / sandwiched

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't "lost", you just executed a trade with a wide margin from market price. Prices on Uniswap, and most DEXes really, are based on liquidity (how much assets people have deposited to the pool) and how much you are trying to trade. Less liquidity and higher input amount means worse price

The UI you executed this trade from would have shown you the estimated price as well as a % from that price you are willing to execute the trade at